# Ruby listing only the local variables I defined

Tags: ruby, local-variables

```
loriginal=local_variables

a=1
b=2 
c=3

lvar=local_variables-loriginal  

puts "..........."
lvar.each{|v| puts v}  
puts "-----------"
```

I would like to print all the local variables I defined -> a,b,c.
If I simply print local_variables I get a lot of stuff I don't want.
At someone's suggestion I tried the above, but when I try it all the variables appear in lorignal (including a,b,c ).

Is there a way to just print a,b,c?

Comment: Do you want the names of the variable, or their contents?

Comment: @the Tin Man. Actually local_variables returns a list of symbols, and that is basically what I want symbols.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=1
b=2 
c=3

local_variables.each{|v| puts v}
```

I guess you mean you might have other variables in your code but you just want some of them in particular. How about putting them into a function and then calling `local_variables`? It will only print those variables inside the function.

If you store the variables in a list you can still do anything you want with them afterwards.

```
unwanted=23

def ada
  a=1
  b=2
  c=3

  puts local_variables
  return a,b,c
end

mygoodlist=ada()

#not really necessary
p=0
mygoodlist.each{|e| p=p+e}
puts p
```